# Send an image from c++ in rabbitmq with protocol buffer to c#

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers

I want to send an image from c++ project to a c# project with rabbitmq and protocol buffer. I am reading an image from a file with opencv and saving it into a matrix. The question is how to send the image to the c# project? Should i convert the matrix into byte array or into string? and how to declare the type in the c# project?

I have this `LPRResult.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto2"
package ProtoBufLPR;

message LPRResult {
   required string LicencsePlate = 1;
   required bytes Image = 2;
}
```

Read the image and send the message:

```
using byte = unsigned char;
int sendMessage() {

 Mat image;
    image = imread("/home/capture4.jpeg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    ProtobufLPR::LPRResult lprResult;

    //convert to byte array
    int size = image.total() * image.elemSize();
    byte * bytes = new byte[size];  // you will have to delete[] that later
    std::memcpy(bytes, image.data, size * sizeof(byte));

    lprResult.set_image(bytes, sizeof(byte));

    lprResult.set_licenseplatenumber("1234567");

    SimplePocoHandler handler("10.0.0.6", 5672);

    AMQP::Connection connection(&handler, AMQP::Login("guest", "guest"), "/");
    AMQP::Channel channel(&connection);

    channel.onReady([&]()
    {
        if(handler.connected())
        {

            int size = lprResult.ByteSize();
            char* array = new char[size];
            lprResult.SerializeToArray(array, size);

            channel.publish("", "hello", array);
            std::cout << " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'" << std::endl;
            handler.quit();
        }
    });
}
```

If send the data like this i am getting an error on the c# :

> Invalid wire-type; this usually means you have over-written a file without truncating or setting the length

My class in c#:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;

namespace LPRRabbitMq
{
    [ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
    public class LPRResult
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public String LicensePlateNumber { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public Byte[] Image { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is my c# deserialize code:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


namespace LPRRabbitMq
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                HostName = "10.0.0.6",
                UserName = "guest",
                Password = "guest",
                VirtualHost = "/",
                Port = 5672
            };

            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                                     durable: false,
                                     exclusive: false,
                                     autoDelete: false,
                                     arguments: null);


                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {

                    LPRResult result;

                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(ea.Body))
                    {
                       result = Serializer.Deserialize<LPRResult>(stream);

                        Console.WriteLine(result.LicensePlateNumber);
                    }

                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
                };
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                                     autoAck: true,
                                     consumer: consumer);

                Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I see the c# deserialize code? This type of thing is often an error in either transferring or processing the data before it gets to the serializer. If you have a capture of the raw payload, you can use https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode to test whether it matches what you expect. You can also use  https://protogen.marcgravell.com/ to generate protobuf-net types from .proto, but the class you've shown looks fine (it is a simple scenario, thankfully). My other suspicion is whether there's some "wrapper" around the payload that is specific to the rabbit piece.

Comment: If you have demo data (a dummy string and image that is fine to share on the public internet), and you can post the payload as hex, base-64 or as a raw file somewhere, I'd happily take a look. But as I say, the first thing I'd love to see the your c# code that is calling deserialize

Comment: The other thing I'd look at: does rabbit know that it is sending binary / is it binary-safe? If it only expects text, it might be running it through an encoding like utf-8 at each end, which would make a real mess of the payload

Comment: @MarcGravell I updated the question

Comment: And why are you using char* on c++ side if you are sending binary data?

Comment: @Evk Is there another option?

Comment: With the edit, it looks like `ea.Body` is indeed binary, which suggests it *should* work. I suggest using `Convert.ToBase64String(ea.Body)` to get the base-64 which you can feed into the "decode" page I linked earlier, to see if it matches the expected shape. If you're unsure how to interpret that data, please feel free to just post the base-64 of a test message here, and mention (@marc in a comment) me, and I'll take a look

Comment: To answer to your question, if you should use byte or String. Byte are the good container. If you use a String, your data MUST be encoded in UTF-8. And all the byte sequence are not valid UTF-8 sequence. So, using byte is the appropriate container. If you want to use a string anyway, you will need to convert your raw bytes into base64. Where base64 is appropriate to be used in a string.

Comment: @Luc Thank you for the suggestion. I prefer to use bytes, but what is the proper way to do that? It is working with the string and base64 but i don't want to send a huge string over the network.

Comment: @Evk `SerializeToString(&buffer)` is better?

Comment: If you want to use Bytes, you just need to do the same process, without the Base64 encoding/decoding. So you will have raw bytes in your protobuf.